# Count number of times combination of events occurs in dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have a data frame and I want to calculate the number of times each combination of events in two columns occur (in any order).

For example say I have

```
df <- data.frame('x' = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
                 'y' = c('b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'))
```

So

```
x y  
a b  
a c  
b c  
c a  
c a  
c a  
c b
```

`a` and `b` occur together once (1st row), `a` and `c` 4 times (rows 2, 4, 5, 6) and `b` and `c` twice (3rd and 7th rows) so I would want to return

```
x-y num  
a-b 1  
a-c 4  
b-c 2
```

I hope this makes sense? Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you're saying order doesn't matter, right?

Comment: Yes, order doesn't matter. Think Rcosters answer below does the trick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
table(apply(df,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse='-')))

a-b a-c b-c 
  1   3   2
```

Comment: Thanks, this does as I want

Comment: I have an extention to this problem - if there is a possible combination of values which does not appear if the columns then I want to return these with value 0. i.i if we had the above but without the top row which was a combination of a & b the output would be
a-b a-c b-c
 0   3   2
Is there an easy way of doing this without finding all possible variations in another functions and then finding the missing values from our initial output?
Thanks

Comment: You can do it with `expand.grid()` and `factor()` functions. Create a new question and I'll (or another person) answer there.

Comment: Thanks Rcoster, I have asked the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475832/count-number-of-time-combination-of-events-appear-in-dataframe-columns-ext