# Count number of time combination of events appear in dataframe columns ext

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

This is an extension of the question asked in [Count number of times combination of events occurs in dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899197/count-number-of-times-combination-of-events-occurs-in-dataframe-columns), I will reword the question again so it is all here:

I have a data frame and I want to calculate the number of times each combination of events in two columns occur (in any order), with a zero if a combination doesn't appear.

For example say I have

```
df <- data.frame('x' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
                 'y' = c('c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'))
```

So

```
x y  
a c  
b c  
c a  
c a  
c a  
c b
```

`a` and `b` do not occur together, `a` and `c` 4 times (rows 2, 4, 5, 6) and `b` and `c` twice (3rd and 7th rows) so I would want to return

```
x-y num  
a-b 0  
a-c 4  
b-c 2
```

I hope this makes sense? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your data.frame data and what you wrote below do not correspond. (one too few a-c combos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, you can do this with `factor()` and `expand.grid()` (or another way to get all possible combinations)

```
all.possible <- expand.grid(c('a','b','c'), c('a','b','c'))
all.possible <- all.possible[all.possible[, 1] != all.possible[, 2], ]
all.possible <- unique(apply(all.possible, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse='-')))

df <- data.frame('x' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
                 'y' = c('c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'))
table(factor(apply(df , 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse='-')), levels=all.possible))
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
res = table(df)
```

To convert to data frame:

```
resdf = as.data.frame(res)
```

The resdf data.frame looks like:

```
  x y Freq
1 a a    0
2 b a    0
3 c a    2
4 a b    0
5 b b    0
6 c b    1
7 a c    1
8 b c    1
9 c c    0
```

Note that this answer takes order into account.  If ordering of the columns is unimportant, then modifying the original data.frame prior to the process will remove the effect of ordering (a-c treated the same as c-a).

```
df1 = as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1,sort)))
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, because I was a bit bored. Perhaps a bit more generalised? But probably still uglier than it could be...

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df))
df2$com <- apply(df2[,1:2],1,function(x) if(x[1] != x[2]) paste(sort(x),collapse='-'))
df2 <- df2[df2$com != "NULL",]
ddply(df2, .(unlist(com)), summarise, 
      num = sum(Freq))
```