# Find number of unique combinations in data frame and Number of observations in each combination

Tags: r, combinations

This question follows from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475832/count-number-of-time-combination-of-events-appear-in-dataframe-columns-ext). Instead of having two columns, what if we have three or more columns? Consider the following data.

```
x <- c(600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800,
       600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800,
       600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800)

y <- c(1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
       80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80,
       3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3)

z <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,
       1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,
       1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)

xyz <- data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))
```

If we treat all columns as factor with finite number of levels. What I want to get is the number of observations in each unique combination of x, y and z. The answer is 18 unique combinations with 3 observations in each combination. How can I do this in R, please? Thank you!

Comment: you can try `unique(xyz)`

Comment: @HubertL Sure. That gives unique combinations. But I also what to know how many observations there are in each unique combination. Is there an easy way to do so, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `table` or `tabulate` with `interaction`

```
tabulate(with(xyz, interaction(x,y,z)))

table(with(xyz, interaction(x,y,z)))
```

or `split` by the interaction and use `lengths`,

```
lengths(split(xyz, with(xyz, interaction(x,y,z))))
```

or

```
aggregate(seq_along(x)~ x+y+z, data=xyz, FUN=length)
```

Comment: what package is `lengths` part of?

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(xyz)`, grouped by the columns of 'xyz', get the number of elements in each group (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xyz)[, .N, names(xyz)]$N
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Or with `dplyr`, we group by the columns, get the number of elements (`n()`) using `summarise`.

```
library(dplyr)
xyz %>%
    group_by_(.dots=names(xyz)) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    .$n
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```