# How to add a column that counts duplicates in sequence?

Tags: r

I'm looking to add a column to a data frame (integrates2) that counts duplicates in sequence. Below is what the data looks like:

```
name    program  date of contact   helper column
John     ffp        10/11/2014          2
John     TP         10/27/2014          2
Carlos   TP         11/19/2015          3
Carlos   ffp        12/1/2015           3
Carlos   wfd        12/31/2015          3
Jen      ffp        9/9/2014            2
Jen      TP         9/30/2014           2
```

This is a list of people who've attended certain programs on certain dates. I've added a helper column to count duplicates and sorted the date of contact. I am looking to count the combinations of programs that exist (e.g. ffp-tp, tp-ffp-wfd).

In order to do this I want to implement the following code in order to transpose the ordered combinations with the help of a new column named "program2":

```
 #transpose the programs 
 require(reshape2) dcast(integrates2, name ~ program2, value.var=”program”)
```

Then I plan to use the following code to turn the result into a table and data frame and count frequencies:

```
 res = table(integrates2)
 resdf = as.data.frame(res)
```

I saw this used in the following link:
[Count number of time combination of events appear in dataframe columns ext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475832/count-number-of-time-combination-of-events-appear-in-dataframe-columns-ext)

What I need from "program2" is to look like this:

```
  Name    program  date of contact   helper column   program2
  John     ffp        10/11/2014          2             1
  John     TP         10/27/2014          2             2
  Carlos   TP         11/19/2015          3             1
  Carlos   ffp        12/1/2015           3             2
  Carlos   wfd        12/31/2015          3             3
```

This way, I can use "program2" to transpose into different columns and then count the combinations. The final result should look something like this:

```
    program  pro1   pro2   freq      
     ffp     tp             2   
     TP      ffp    wfd     1
```

I'm sure there are easier ways to do this, but as I am learning, this is where I am. Appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this question, I think the following would be the way to go. If you do not mind combining all program names, you could do the following. This is probably much better.

```
setDT(mydf)[, list(type = paste(program, collapse = "-")), by = name][,
           list(total = .N), by = type]

#         type total
#1:     ffp-TP     2
#2: TP-ffp-wfd     1
```

If you want to separate program names, you can do that with `cSplit()` from the `splitstackshape` package.

```
setDT(mydf)[, list(type = paste(program, collapse = "-")), by = name][,
              list(total = .N), by = type] -> temp

cSplit(temp, splitCols = "type", sep = "-")

#   total type_1 type_2 type_3
#1:     2    ffp     TP     NA
#2:     1     TP    ffp    wfd
```

The equivalence of dplyr code is:

```
group_by(mydf, name) %>%
summarise(type = paste(program, collapse = "-")) %>%
count(type)

#        type     n
#       (chr) (int)
#1     ffp-TP     2
#2 TP-ffp-wfd     1
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(name = c("John", "John", "Carlos", "Carlos", "Carlos", 
"Jen", "Jen"), program = c("ffp", "TP", "TP", "ffp", "wfd", "ffp", 
"TP"), dateOfContact = c("10/11/2014", "10/27/2014", "11/19/2015", 
"12/1/2015", "12/31/2015", "9/9/2014", "9/30/2014"), helperColumn = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("name", "program", "dateOfContact", 
"helperColumn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Jazzurro, thanks! I used the setDT function as you wrote your code and it worked out well. I'm going to test the dplyr code as well.

Comment: @LoF10 Pleasure to help you. :)

Comment: quick question, let's say I wanted to keep name, or an id variable so later I could merge this with another data set, how could I alter the code to keep names? i tried the following but it didn't work: setDT(mydf)[, list(type = paste(name, program, collapse = "-")), by = name][,
           list(total = .N), by = type]. I assumed "paste" would allow me to add another vector "name". Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @LoF10 The final result shows the frequency of the program patterns. So you have John and Jen under the type of `ffp-TP`. If you want to add a column for name, how would you like to have it?

Comment: @LoF10 Are you looking for something like this? `setDT(mydf)[, list(type = paste(program, collapse = "-")), by = name][, list(total = .N, name = paste(name, collapse = ",")), by = type]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Return permutations

With `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
integrates2 %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(prg1 = program[1],
                                             prg2 = program[2],
                                             prg3 = program[3]) %>% 
  select(prg1, prg2, prg3) %>% group_by(prg1, prg2, prg3) %>% summarise(freq = n())
```

returns

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: prg1, prg2 [?]

    prg1   prg2   prg3  freq
  (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (int)
1    ffp     TP     NA     2
2     TP    ffp    wfd     1
```

With `mydf2` from the comments, it produces

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: prg1, prg2 [?]

   prg1  prg2  prg3  freq
  (chr) (chr) (chr) (int)
1   ffp    TP    NA     1
2    TP   ffp    NA     1
3   wfd    TP   ffp     1
```

The chain

- calls `group_by` on `name` to separates cases;
- `summarise` to transpose `program` into three columns;
- `select` to narrow to those columns;
- `group_by` all `prg*` columns so
- `summarise` can chop them down to unique groups and add a `freq` count of occurrences from those groups.

---

Alternately, you can do the whole thing in base R if you like, though it's considerably less readable (with this particular approach, at least):

```
tab <- table(sapply(split(integrages2$program, integrates2$name), 
             function(x){paste(x, collapse = '-')}))
prgs <- strsplit(names(tab), '-')
programs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(prgs, function(x){
  c(x, rep(NA, max(sapply(prgs, length)-length(x))))
  }))
programs <- cbind(as.data.frame(programs), matrix(tab))
names(programs) <- c(paste0('prgm', seq(length(programs)-1)), 'freq')
```

---

A very quick-and-dirty version, which collapses the series into strings:

```
table(sapply(split(integrates2$program, integrates2$name), 
             function(x){paste(x, collapse = '-')}))
```

returns

```
ffp-TP TP-ffp-wfd 
     2          1
```

or if wrapped in `as.matrix`,

```
           [,1]
ffp-TP        2
TP-ffp-wfd    1
```

---

### Pre-edit version: Return combinations

Using `reshape2`, you can use `dcast` to make a data.frame of program combinations (chopping out `name`s, which we don't care about, with `[,-1]`):

```
library(reshape2)
programs <- dcast(integrates2, name ~ program, value.var = 'program')[,-1]
```

`programs` looks like:

```
> programs
  ffp TP  wfd
1 ffp TP  wfd
2 ffp TP <NA>
3 ffp TP <NA>
```

You can now use `dplyr` to group by all the column names of `programs` (done programmatically here, but you can do it by hand with `group_by(ffp, TP, wfd)` if you prefer to see what's going on) and `summarise`, using `n()` to grab counts of how many rows are in the groups:

```
library(dplyr)
programs %>% group_by_(.dots = names(programs)) %>% summarise(freq = n())
```

which returns

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: ffp, TP [?]

    ffp    TP   wfd  freq
  (chr) (chr) (chr) (int)
1   ffp    TP   wfd     1
2   ffp    TP    NA     2
```

Comment: I am playing with the original data. I use the following modified data and  I am not getting an expected outcome with your code. Am I missing something? `mydf2 <- structure(list(name = c("John", "John", "Carlos", "Carlos", "Carlos", "Jen", "Jen"), program = c("TP", "ffp", "wfd", "TP", "ffp", "ffp", "TP"), dateOfContact = c("10/11/2014", "10/27/2014", "11/19/2015", "12/1/2015", "12/31/2015", "9/9/2014", "9/30/2014"), helperColumn = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("name", "program", "dateOfContact", "helperColumn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))`

Comment: @jazzurro It works fine for me, if you put in `mydf2` for `integrates2` in the line that makes `programs` (the name of the original data.frame, according to the OP).

Comment: Do you see three different program patterns in the end? I followed your code, I ended up seeing only two patterns although there should be three patterns; mydf2 has three different program patterns.

Comment: OH, I see, I read the question differently. I took it as combinations, not permutations, in the sense that order doesn't matter with combinations. Rereading, it's not clear which was intended... @LoF10 can you clarify?

Comment: "transpose the ordered combinations", definitely looking for permutations where order does matter. That's why I sorted initially by name and then date of contact *with(integrates2, arrange(name, date of contact). I'm trying to see which program paths are most common and then tie those to outcomes later. so in this particular data frame there are only two program paths: "ffp-tp" and "tp-ffp-wfd".